# How do I remove this potential leak? (iOS7)

Tags: memory-leaks, ios7

I'm getting this issue.  What's the best way to fix it?

[image]

Comment: Please post the code here and not just a picture.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: picture was posted for the clang annotations; harder to show in plain text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [LLVM docs on ARC](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html):

> - `(__bridge T)` op casts the operand to the destination type T. If T is a retainable object pointer type, then op must have a non-retainable pointer type. ...
> - `(__bridge_retained T)` op casts the operand, which must have retainable object pointer type, to the destination type, which must be a non-retainable pointer type. ARC retains the value, subject to the usual optimizations on local values, and the recipient is responsible for balancing that +1.

By using a retained bridge cast, you've asked ARC to retain the value.
But it looks like in your case you do not plan on taking responsibility of the memory management of the `colors` object. So the retained bridge would seem to be incorrect, and you want just the `__bridge` cast instead.

Comment: Thank you very much. That solved it. I was tired and lazy, so I didn't read the docs. But I appreciate you pointing them out.